# Make file error: make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'staging'. Stop

Tags: linux, makefile

Pulling my hair out with this one. I'm sure it's super simple. When I run:

`make django_servers ENV="staging"`

On the below Makefile I get the following error when it hits line `$(MAKE) scoring_worker_servers ${ENV}`:

`make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'staging'.  Stop.`

I've included the whole Makefile.

```
# Put any command that doesn't create a file here (almost all of the commands)
.PHONY: \
    help \
    beat_servers \
    database_servers \
    default_celery_worker_servers \
    django_servers \
    webapp_servers \
    rabbit_servers \
    renew_ssl \
    scoring_worker_servers \

usage:
    @echo "Available commands:"
    @echo "help                     Display available commands"
    @echo "beat_servers             Push ansible config to beat_servers"
    @echo "database_servers         Push ansible config to database servers"
    @echo "default_celery_worker_servers    Push ansible config to default celery worker servers"
    @echo "django_servers           Push ansible config to django servers"
    @echo "webapp_servers           Push ansible config to webapp servers"
    @echo "rabbit_servers           Push ansible config to rabbit servers"
    @echo "renew_ssl                Renew SSL certificates and push to required servers"
    @echo "scoring_worker_servers   Push ansible config to scoring worker servers"

help:
    $(MAKE) usage

beat_servers:
    @ansible-playbook ansible/beat_servers.yml -i ansible/inventories/${ENV}/beat --vault-id ansible/password.txt

database_servers:
    @ansible-playbook ansible/database_servers.yml -i ansible/inventories/${ENV}/database --vault-id ansible/password.txt

default_celery_worker_servers:
    @ansible-playbook ansible/default_celery_worker_servers.yml -i ansible/inventories/${ENV}/default_celery_worker --vault-id ansible/password.txt

scoring_worker_servers:
    @ansible-playbook ansible/scoring_worker_servers.yml -i ansible/inventories/${ENV}/scoring_worker --vault-id ansible/password.txt

django_servers:
    @ansible-playbook ansible/django_servers.yml -i ansible/inventories/${ENV}/django --vault-id ansible/password.txt
    $(MAKE) default_celery_worker_servers ${ENV}
    $(MAKE) scoring_worker_servers ${ENV}
    $(MAKE) beat_servers ${ENV}

webapp_servers:
    @ansible-playbook ansible/webapp_servers.yml -i ansible/inventories/${ENV}/webapp --vault-id ansible/password.txt

rabbit_servers:
    @ansible-playbook ansible/rabbit_servers.yml -i ansible/inventories/${ENV}/rabbit --vault-id ansible/password.txt

renew_ssl:
    @certbot renew --dns-cloudflare-credentials /cloudflare/cloudflare.ini
    $(MAKE) django_servers ${ENV}
    $(MAKE) webapp_servers ${ENV}
```

Comment: It seems like you're writing an imperative program, where you specify a bunch of steps which should be done in order. Bash is a better fit for this kind of thing. Here's an example of how to write a script with selectable subcommands: https://gist.github.com/waylan/4080362

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass the value of ENV as a parameter to `make`. But you can set the variable for it:

```
$(MAKE) scoring_worker_servers ENV=$(ENV)
```

Comment: ... votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score :(